# Why doesnt my html link change colour after clicking on it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On this webpage when you click on a link in the **Acoustid** column it doesn't change colour to show it has been visited

http://reports.albunack.net/acoustid_report.html

I cant see wny, there is nothing special in the html

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://acoustid.org/track/1eb887d3-5c75-4533-b508-7c17a118b07b" target="_blank" title="Acoustid Page">
                        1eb887d3-5c75-4533-b508-7c17a118b07b
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Nelly Furtado/my love grows deeper
                </td>
                <td>
                    5
                </td>
                <td>
                    Nelly Furtado/maneater
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://acoustid.org/track/123feaa4-2464-495c-bb76-d4dad91ffca3" target="_blank" title="Acoustid Page">
                        123feaa4-2464-495c-bb76-d4dad91ffca3
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Nelly Furtado/on the radio
                </td>
                <td>
                    69
                </td>
                <td>
                    Nelly Furtado/....on the radio (remember the days)
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and I cant see anything in the css either

Comment: Do you have a css reset removing the `:visited` selector?

Comment: I believe bootstraps reboot sass is causing this.  You need to add a:visited{color:red} to your albunack.css file.    you can also control hover and focus states.   If you want to add a class to the p tag that wraps the a tags you can specify those with .yourclass a:visited{color:pink}

Comment: OK for reasons I wont go into I tried to just apply inline to the a but didnt work <a href="[http://acoustid.org/track/d1f58778-ab15-421b-af2c-8f146deed15c](view-source:http://acoustid.org/track/d1f58778-ab15-421b-af2c-8f146deed15c)" target="_blank" style="a:visited {color:green;}"> d1f58778-ab15-421b-af2c-8f146deed15c </a> dont suppose you know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Okay I have working my modifying albunack.css as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS

```
a:visited {
  color: red; // #565656 hex code for any other color in place of red
}
```

Change red to any color of your choice eg. #ff0000 for any other color code

Comment: This worked, as suggested by Cameron the issue was due to be using Bootstrap, and Bootstrap disables visited changing link colour, I did not realize that.

Answer (score 1):

For the links to  change color when they have been visted you will have to  specify it in your css document . For example you hv to specifie what should happen when the link is not visited ,  visited   and when its active. Note that if u dont specifie these there it automatically fall under defualt setting to which may vary based on the browser

Comment: But dont they change colour by default ?

Comment: not if you defined a fixed text color for the link

Comment: Just as tacoshy outlined when u define a fixed color it means the link color is fixed in other words its not going to change  even whenthe link  is active or  it have been visted . The color will be the specified one.

Comment: the link does change when you hover over it though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).